# Select count of records that have a relationship that has its own relationship condition?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables. `PartFlights` and `Parts`. A `Part` can (potentially) have many `PartFlights`, a `PartFlight` has one and only one `Part`.

```
+----------------------+---------+
|   part_flights_pivot |  part   |
+----------------------+---------+
| part_flight_id       | part_id |
| part_id              |         |
+----------------------+---------+
```

The question I'm asking is: **How many `PartFlights` are there that have reused `Parts`?**

Getting this into SQL is turning out horribly for me. I've identified some conditions however:

- Ultimately, I need a count statement to add the result up.
- I need to join `PartFlight` to `Part`.
- For `Parts` that have been reused, I need to exclude the first `PartFlight`, as that `PartFlight` is not using a reused `Part` at the time, but a new one.

I managed to produce the following query:

```
SELECT part_flights_pivot.part_flight_id, part_flights_pivot.part_id, COUNT(parts.part_id)-1 as count, SUM(count) FROM part_flights_pivot
JOIN parts ON part_flights_pivot.part_id=parts.part_id
GROUP BY (parts.part_id)
HAVING COUNT(parts.part_id)-1 > 0
```

And while it returns results, I don't believe those results are precisely correct.

Comment: How are you defining 'reused'? Are you asking how many partflights have parts that are in other partflights?

Comment: @LordBaconPants Not precisely. By analogy, if a new plane is flown, that plane flight is not using a 'reused' plane, but a new one. The next plane flight to use that plane is however using what can be considered a 'reused' plane in the sense that it's been used before.

Comment: How in the data is "reused" indicated?

Comment: @JohnDoe, it's not - I don't store any value or boolean indicating reuse. I'm presuming that data can be reconstructed by determining if a `Part` has more than one `PartFlight`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is given that every single part_flight must carry one and only one part_id, this query can be constructed on the part_flights table only. However, I've constructed the query assuming there are other fields we require from the parts table. (If we required nothing unique from the Parts table this could be stripped down to the code within the parens.)  I believe our correct query is along these lines  :

```
    select p.*, t.counter
    from parts p
    (select part_id, count(*)-1 counter
    from part_flights_pivot 
    group by part_id
    having count(*)>1) t
    where p.part_id = t.part_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a sub-query:

```
SELECT Part.* FROM Part WHERE
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PartFlight WHERE
        PartFlight.key = Part.key) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by "reuse" you mean count all the part flights that used a part for the second time or more, you could use a subquery to number the part flights for each part, then count the part flights excluding the "first" part flight for each part (note you don't actually need to join to "Parts" to do this count, although you'll probably want to join the result to get part name or other attributes):

```
SELECT
   part_id, 
   count(*) AS part_reuse_count
FROM 
(
SELECT 
   @row_number := CASE 
     WHEN @part_id = part_id THEN @row_number + 1 
     ELSE 1 
     END as rownum,
   @part_id := part_id AS part_id,
   part_flight_id
FROM 
   part_flight
ORDER BY 
   part_id, 
   part_flight_id
  ) x
WHERE 
  rownum <> 1 -- exclude the first part_flight for each part
GROUP BY 
  part_id
ORDER BY 
  part_id
```

[Example on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/820a9c/1/0)